# Removing responsive elements

Tags: css, tumblr

**Website:** http://jimouk.tumblr.com

I'm attempting to remove a few responsive elements from a Tumblr theme I downloaded. I've created a few rollover effects and when the site goes below 1024px it messes them up. I also don't like how it looks, and Tumblr has its own mobile theme.

This is what it's doing that I don't want it to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK81j.jpg

I would like it to remain the same no matter what the screen resolution is. If it generated a scrollbar past 1024px that would be even better instead of it stacking the menu on top of the content.

There are a number of @media CSS elements which I've adjusted, and tried to outright remove but none of them seem to be doing the trick. For the life of me I can't seem to figure out what is causing the content stacking when the screen goes below 1024px.

Comment: Also this is what I would like it to look like no matter what the browser size is, I was unable to add more then two links to my original post: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AIDaG.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to advise you without re-writing all of the CSS to show you how to do it. I took a look at the source and the theme is 'mobile-first' (i.e. the default layout is the mobile layout, and the media queries augment the CSS to change the layout when the viewport is wider). You can see what I mean here, with the container housing your blog's posts:

```
.the-posts {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .the-posts {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .the-posts {
    float: right;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: -88px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .the-posts.ready {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

So, when the browser window's width is above 1024px, the `.the-posts` element is moved to the right of the screen.

Instead, you should replace the default `.the-posts` CSS rules with the desktop rules and remove all of the media query rules:

```
.the-posts {
    float: right;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: -88px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

You need to repeat this exercise for the other elements, too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured this out by leaving the @media queries in the CSS but adding additional ones for the absolute position elements in my design so they are hidden when the screen shifts for smaller resolutions. This solved the issue of things looking wonky and I was able to keep the responsive design.

Comment: @Jimo: Nice, I'm glad you got it working the way you want it to. The logo rollover effect is very cool, by the way!